# Objective c NSTimer interval time setting

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, timer, nstimer

After the "startButton" button is clicked,it trigger timer to execute "myCalculation" every 5 s.
Problem : execution time of myCalculation method spends around 5-10s to complete

Q1.How I can set a suitable time interval to the timer ? (I think set time interval to 10s is too long ,  program will get 5s idle if retrieveAndUpdateNews  spends 5s to complete)

In current situation , although myCalculation need 10s to complete , the timer will skip to execute retrieveAndUpdateNews and trigger the retrieveAndUpdateNews 5s later.

Q2.Are this a protential problem for my app?
Thanks for your time.

```
-(IBAction) startButton : (id)sender{
NSTimer * myTimer;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 
      target:self
      selector:@selector(retrieveAndUpdateNews)  
      userInfo:nil repeats:YES];                                   
}                      

-(void)retrieveAndUpdateNews{
    //some calculation spend  5 - 10  sec.
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a timer? What are you doing that takes 5 to 10 seconds? Do you really want to start 5 seconds after the calculation finishes each time?

Comment: Very sorry about my typo, "myCalculation" should change to "retrieveAndUpdateNews" . My task is let user to press "startButton" , then program will keep retrieve data from web server and update the data to frontend's label.It takes 5-10s to complete depends on server's respone time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want is to start your timer when the user presses the button and then stop it while the data is processed on the server and downloaded and then restart it after the data is received so you can refresh again. Something like:

```
- (IBAction) startButton:(id)sender {
    [self beginDownloadCycle];
}

- (void)beginDownloadCycle {
    self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 
      target:self
      selector:@selector(retrieveAndUpdateNews)  
      userInfo:nil
      repeats:NO]; 
}                    

- (void)retrieveAndUpdateNews {
    // some calculation spend  5 - 10  sec with completion block.
    [... :^() {
        [self beginDownloadCycle];
    }];
}
```

Note that the timer should be retained so that you can cancel it if required and so that you know what's going on (hence the `self.myTimer =`).

Comment: What happens when ARC destroys the `myTimer` instance?

Comment: @Droppy good question, the runloop retains the timer but it is a good idea to maintain a reference to the timer so you can update if required so I've made an edit

Answer (score 0):

It's probably no the right approach to guess how much it time your calculation would take (especially since it will vary on different devices). Why don't you utilise `gcd` and receive a "callback" exactly when you calculation is finished?

Here is how it might look like (assuming you want to perform your calculation on the background thread):

```
- (IBAction)startButton:(id)sender {

    [self doSomethingWithCompletionCallback:^{
        [self retrieveAndUpdateNews];
    }];
}

- (void)doSomethingWithCompletionCallback:(void (^)(void))callback {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    /// do some work
        callback();
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Dariaa , thanks your comment.As I need to execute "retrieveAndUpdateNews" continuously after user press the start button.I am not familiar with GCD yet, do you mean I need to add the timer to GCD in my task? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problem you can use

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector
         withObject:(id)anArgument
         afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```

Also inside your "retrieveAndUpdateNews" call the method again using performSelector. So it is going to a recursive call. To cancel the performSelector use

```
- (void)cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id)aTarget
```